# Change focal point in Rviz automatically

Tags: ros, pcl, librviz, 3d-visualization, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I believe the focal point of a view in Rviz is the point the camera rotates around. How can I set the values for the focal point automatically? Say I have a node which is publishing the center of mass of a point cloud and I want my view in Rviz to rotate around that point - how can that be achieved?

Thanks!
Jay

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222091/change-focal-point-in-rviz-automatically/) by [Jay4Ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25243/jay4ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See if the [rviz_animated_view_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz_animated_view_controller) package offers what you need.

---

Edit:

> Are there examples in C++?

No, there are not, afaik. But this is all really basic msg publication, so should be trivial to re-create in other languages.

> Once I publish cameraPlacement messages - how can I tell Rviz to deal with them accordingly?

From the wik page on `rviz_animated_view_controller`:

> This package provides an RViz view controller plugin [..]

This particular view controller shows up in the drop-down list in the [Views Panel](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide#Views_Panel) in RViz.

---

Edit 2: from the RViz User Guide I linked, it appears you might also be able to achieve what you want by publishing a TF frame at the location of the CoM and by selecting the [Third Person Follower](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide#Third_Person_Follower) camera, but I can't find that anymore in recent RViz versions. I doubt it will also automatically *rotate* around the frame though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jay4Ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25243/jay4ros/) on 2015-12-08**:
Thanks! I have installed the package and had a look at the examples. I believe I could achieve what I am looking for by setting the focus point. 1. Are there examples in C++? 2. Once I publish cameraPlacement messages - how can I tell Rviz to deal with them accordingly?

**Comment by [Jay4Ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25243/jay4ros/) on 2015-12-08**:
Thanks! I have written a publisher, publishing on a topic with message type view_controller_msgs::CameraPlacement. But this topic does not show under the "Type" field in Rviz View Panel. If I start CameraTest from the examples, nothing happens as well. What am I missing?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-08**:
A topic is never supposed to 'show up', it will only interact with the view controller plugin. If you've installed things correctly, you should find an *Animated* item in the *Type* drop down of the *Views* panel.

**Comment by [Jay4Ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25243/jay4ros/) on 2015-12-08**:
Ah, restarting Rviz did the trick. Setting the focus point works, however, "eye" gets set all the time as well. This is counterintuitive unfortunately, because things like zooming by the user are senseless now :( How can I set eye to the value the user specified?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-08**:
I'm not an expert user of this pkg, I just suggested it might do what you were after. I'm not sure whether it is possible to retrieve what you want. You might want to extend the package to only control the focus, not the rest.

**Comment by [Jay4Ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25243/jay4ros/) on 2015-12-08**:
Hmm..then I am afraid I am stuck here. I would not know how to extend the package to fix my problem.